# Upload file in node.js multipart/form-data to api

Tags: node.js, api, file

I have to upload a file to an API using nodejs, the thing is, it doesnt accept a JSON object and I need to send it (cant convert it to string). Any Idea how can I send that file, with also an JSON object? (any nodejs module?)

```
var formData = {
    profile: config.widenProfile,
    filename: "example.pdf",
    file: fs.createReadStream(path),
    metadata: jsonObj,  //cant send it because of this
};
      var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: config.api,
      formData:formData,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+config.token
      }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
      console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
      console.log('Response:', body);
    });
```

Comment: Please look at this

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? I tested using a simple JSON and it seems to work, remember you need to flatten the JSON with multiple depths and array for this to work, but I think you can write a generic function to do it.

On the server side you will receive the JSON object in the field called 'jsonObj', let me know if this helps

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");


var  jsonObj = {
    "name" : "value",
    "name1" : "value1",
    "integer_val" : 1,
    "integer_val2" : 2
}
var payload = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/PDFReader',
    headers:
        {'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
    proxy: '',
    json:true,
    formData:
        {  pdf: fs.createReadStream("./ICR.PDF")
        }
};

var keys = Object.keys(jsonObj);

keys.forEach(function(key) {
    var formatKey = 'jsonObj[' + key + ']';
    payload.formData[formatKey] =jsonObj[key];
});
console.log(payload);
request(payload, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```